# Find an object's mesh in bpy.data.meshes

Tags: python

Simple question: How can I find an objects mesh in bpy.data.meshes?

e.g.

```
ob = context.scene.active_object
bpy.data.meshes[ob.data]???
```

Is it possible without looping over the complete bpy.data.meshes and comparing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you have a reference to object, then you have a reference to its Mesh too.

```
obj = context.scene.active_object

# all three of the following lines will refer to the same Mesh.
mesh = obj.data
mesh = bpy.data.meshes[obj.data.name]
mesh = bpy.data.meshes[mesh.name]
```

[image]